# can i use fancybox for an online form contact?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm creating a contact form, which I want to be pop out (and greyed) and wanted to know if fancybox could be used for this purpose. I currently use it for images but curious to see if it could work for this purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use fancy box for a form.

You might have to make some changes to the plugin to get it work though

[you can see how to do it here](http://fancybox.net/blog)

Based on your comment: There are a few ways to get that done:-)

One way, is to have multiple divs within the form. Make the next button hide one div and show another in the modal. This can be done as many times as you need to do it within the same modal. Then when the form is complete, you can have a submit button now instead of a next or previous button.

Comment: i guess the main problem i am having is that i wanted to fill out a portion of the form, then have a 'next' which goes to other fiels. Any idea how this can be done? thanks